# Does contrapositive implies converse always true?

Tags: logic

What is wrong with the following argument?

Suppose that $P\implies Q$ is true and $P$ is true.

And I want to prove that $Q \implies P$ is true.

I assume otherwise that $Q \implies \neg P$ is true.

By contrapositive, $(Q\implies \neg P) \implies (P \implies \neg Q)$ is true.

However $P \implies \neg Q$ is false since $P \implies Q$ is true.

So $Q \implies P$ must be true.

Thanks in advance. And sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: $P$ and $P\Rightarrow Q$ are simultaneously true if and only if $Q$ and $P$ are simultaneously true. Thus $Q\Rightarrow P$ must be true as well.

Comment: Your setup for the contradiction is incorrect; the negation of $Q \implies P$ is not $Q \implies \neg P$.

Comment: @T.Bongers: You don't really mean that, do you? It should be $\neg Q\lor P$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, you're quite right. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If $P$ is true, then $Q\implies P$ is true no matter what $Q$ is, and no matter whether $P\implies Q$ or not.

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be three errors in your argument.

The first is "Suppose ... and $P$ is true. And I want to prove that $Q\implies P$ is true." You have no reason to suppose that $P$ is true. Furthermore, if you do suppose it, then $Q\implies P$ follows by inspection of the truth table for $\implies$.

Second, you wrote "I assume otherwise that $Q\implies\neg P$ is true" as if $Q\implies\neg P$ were (equivalent to) the negation of $Q\implies P$. It is not; again, check the truth tables.

Third,you wrote "However $P\implies\neg Q$ is false since $P\implies Q$ is true", again as if $P\implies\neg Q$ and $P\implies Q$ were (equivalent to) each other's negations. They are not, and they can both be true simultaneously, namely when $P$ is false.  Again, check the truth tables.

Note that, when $P$ is false and $Q$ is true, then $P\implies Q$ and (therefore) its contrapositive $(\neg Q)\to(\neg P)$ are true, but the converse, $Q\implies P$ is false. Since no correct argument could get from true statements to a false one, there's a method to systematically find an error in any argument, like yours, that claims to get from true to false. Namely, see what the argument says in the particular situation at hand, i.e., when $P$ is false and $Q$ is true. This may not detect all the errors in an argument, but it will find at least one.